# Counting duplicate row within a rolling window of a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pd.DataFrame with mixed str/float columns. I would like to count within a (centred) 20 minute window of a row the number of duplicates of that row.

For example:

```
time = [3,4,5,6,10,15,25,27,50]
a = np.ones(len(time))
b = np.zeros(len(time))
c = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd','d','d']

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':time, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})
```

The result I expect from this is:

```
result = [1,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,0]
```

As you can see, result is the same length as the time, and it counts the number of duplicates within 10 'minutes' either side of that row. For example, the row where time=27 has only one duplicate because, while the row with time=50 is a duplicate it is too far away in time to be considered.

A terribly slow and ugly way to get the result would be with a for loop and manually creating a window which moves:

```
result = []

for i, t in zip(df.index, df.time):
    x = df[(df['time']>t-10) & (df['time']<t+10)]
    row = df.loc[i,['a','b','c']]
    res = ((x==row).sum(axis=1)==3).sum()-1
    result.append(res)
```

I require a much faster implementation and have looked at the `.rolling` method of a pandas dataframe but cannot get it to work with multiple columns and with str values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of a way to speed up the process

```
s=pd.Series(df.drop('time',1).apply(tuple,1).map(hash).values,index=df.time)
[ sum(s.loc[x-10:x+10]==y)-1 for x ,y in zip(s.index,s)]
Out[1008]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your extremely quick response! Just going to work on understanding the first line - however, it speeds up the process dramatically and brings the execution time within acceptable limits, so thank you very much.

Comment: @YOBEN_S can you please explain? I couldn't understand the solution. I have a kinda similar problem but need to find duplicate based upon two columns. 
Can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285964/how-to-find-duplicate-based-upon-multiple-columns-in-a-rolling-window-in-pandas